# Python: Dennis Nedry - Security

Tags: python, code-access-security

Has anyone seen Jurrassic Park where Dennis Nedry has protected the system with an animation that says 'You didn't say the magic word' where after the system goes down.

Is it possible to do something similar ikn Python ?

To describe it less humoristic:

A response screen which waits for a condition fulfilled by the user.
And encrypts and locks the system after a certain time.

Is that possible on a linux system by the use of Python ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Humans sometimes make use of implicit speech acts in which communications unmade are assumed to exist. If you are wearing a watch and someone asks you if you know what time it is, the proper response is to announce the current time, not just assure them that you do.

Comment: Oh, really? Please, tell me more

Comment: Humans sometimes make use of sarcastic speech in which the conveyance of humor, rather than information is the actual goal. The proper response is typically a chuckle though, in extreme circumstances, an eye-roll may be more appropriate.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I could only append my comment to yours, and not to the upvotes. My response to your *comment* was a combination of eye-roll and chuckle as detailed above. But I was thinking that upvotes for this answer sort of defeated the point of SO as a place where programmers turn for real information.

Answer (score 1):

In which I attempt to answer the implied question, "And if so, how?"

I think this is really a Linux administration question. You'd have to figure out how to suspend a user's account on the system you're using and then log the current user out. It's likely going to involve the Python script running as a user with privileges greater than the user you're locking out. You don't really want to encrypt, do you? Just prevent access. Once you know how to accomplish all those things (suspend account / deny login, log out user, run script as privileged user, etc.,) it's easy to perform those tasks from a Python script.